# How to connect to my phone from a wearable?

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying to send some message from my wearable to my phone, following instructions from here: 
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages

Before sending a message, I am trying to look up my phone with following line:
`Wearable.getCapabilityClient(this).getAllCapabilities(CapabilityClient.FILTER_REACHABLE);`

Unfortunately no capabilities are returned, so I can't send a message.
I made sure both devices share the same Wifi, to add the wear.xml, and attach a CapabilityClient to the phone app. And I am running the phone app before trying to make the lookup on the watch. No success...

So now I am running out of ideas.
Any hints?

Comment: Can you check if the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413162/) applies to your situation?

Comment: @noogui I was hoping to send a message, but will try the data layer approach...

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake: Didn't use the same signing config for wearable and handheld